# Move head of arrow away from shaft in xymatrix

Tags: graphs, xy-pic

Here's an MWE of what I have at the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix@C=0.3pc{
\textbf{r}:e_{-} & & \textbf{see}:e_{-}\ar@{-o}[r] & (e_{-}\ar@{-o}[r] & t_{-}) & & \textbf{j}:e_{-} \\
 & \txt{object:1}\ar@{<=}[ul]\ar@{<=}[ur]!UR\ar@{=>}[dl]\ar@{=>}[dr]!DR & & \txt{clause:3}\ar@{<=}[ur]\ar@{=>}[dr] & & \txt{subject:2}\ar@{<=}[ull]\ar@{<=}[ur]!UR\ar@{=>}[dll]\ar@{=>}[dr]!DR \\
\textbf{r}:e_{1} & & \textbf{see}:e_{1}\ar@{-o}[r] & (e_{2}\ar@{-o}[r] & t_{3}) & & \textbf{j}:e_{2}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want is for the rightward-pointing arrows to look like the `\multimap` symbol from the amssymb package:

[image]

At the moment I'm mimicking that by using the `\ar@{-o}[r]` arrow in xymatrix.  However, the problem is that what's rendered has the shaft of the arrow going inside the head.  How can I move the shaft and the head of the arrow apart so that it has the appearance I want?  Or is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The one that's defined in the amssymb package.  I'll add that information to the post now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I recommend `tikz-cd` to you?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{%
multimap/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=multimap]},
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small, row sep=7ex]
\textbf{r}:e_{-} \arrow[Rightarrow]{dr} & & \textbf{see}:e_{-} \arrow[Rightarrow]{dl} \arrow[-multimap]{r} & (e_{-} \arrow[Rightarrow]{drr}\arrow[-multimap]{r} & t_{-}) \arrow[Rightarrow, crossing over]{dl} & & \textbf{j}:e_{-} \arrow[Rightarrow]{dl} \\
& \text{object:1} \arrow[Rightarrow]{dr} \arrow[Rightarrow]{dl} & & \text{clause:3} \arrow[Rightarrow]{dr} & & \text{subject:2} \arrow[Rightarrow, crossing over]{dll} \arrow[Rightarrow]{dr} \\
\textbf{r}:e_{1} & & \textbf{see}:e_{1} \arrow[-multimap]{r} & (e_{2} \arrow[-multimap]{r} & t_{3}) & & \textbf{j}:e_{2}
\end{tikzcd}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick with the `Glyph`, did not know that one.